# Saving windows wireless profile credentials

Tags: windows, wifi, credentials

Is there any way to replicate the functionality of "Save credentials" button in the "802.1x settings" menu using Windows API? Or some other way to permanently save the PEAP credentials for the wireless profile.

I've tried the `WlanSetProfileEapXmlUserData` function to set `MsChapV2:Username` and `MsChapV2:Password`. It caches the credentials but does not save them permanently.

**UPD:** Managed to locate the userdata stored in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Wlansvc\UserData\Profiles\{GUID}` but it is encrypted. I guess CryptProtectData is used to encrypt it. If only I knew what kind of salt is used.

Comment: Check out the `netsh wlan` subcommand. Uhm, on second thought, sorry. This is what I would do. I.e. start IDA and then check out something I know implements what I want to see what it does.

Comment: Took a brief look at `netshell.dll`. Check out the functions from `Wlanapi.dll` (introduced in W7). They might get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Seems like `CryptProtectData` is not called from `Wlanapi.dll` directly but through some other function called by RPC. We need to go deeper.

Comment: I found the `CryptProtectData` call in `wlansvc.dll`. Looks like it's the one I need. There is no salt and there is no `LOCAL_MACHINE` flag either. So only **Local System** user can decode the encrypted data. I've managed to decode some profile data created by Windows and it's in some binary format. I suspect that `EapHostPeerCredentialsXml2Blob` is involved here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Wlansvc\UserData\Profiles\{GUID}\MSMUserData` contains the data related to PEAP credentials.
It is encrypted with `CryptProtectData`. Decryption gave us a binary blob which is luckily easy to understand. It contains username and possibly logon domain in plain text. Password info is encrypted again with `CryptProtectData` function and placed towards the end of the blob.

Encryption is done without `LOCAL_MACHINE` flag so only **Local System** user can generate new credentials data. After you place it into the registry key, Windows thinks that you have a saved set of credentials and will never ask for them even in case of failed authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information on WPA2-Enterprise credentials encryption scheme of MSMUserData in my answer https://superuser.com/a/1259271/780533 to the "How can I find Protected EAP credentials of a wireless network stored on Windows 7?" question. In particular, the "unreadable characters" (note that them begin with 01 00 00 00 d0 8c 9d df ...) following the username in the decrypted MSMUserData are the encrypted password so you need to decrypt again using CryptProtectData.